# Cards do BootStrap sobrepondo uns aos outros quando em responsivo

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

Tenho que entregar um site de receitas responsivo feito 100% com bootstrap (nunca tinha usado antes) e sempre que começo a diminuir a tela do site isso acontece https://prnt.sc/cGNRkmemCENB os cards entram um em cima do outro, alguem poderia me dar alguma sugestão do que fazer?

```
<main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 300px; height: 510px">
                        <img src="img/receita-1-230x170.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="receita-1">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Arroz de Couve-Flor</h5>
                            <ul>
                            <li>Arroz</li>
                            <li>Couve-Flor</li>
                            <li>Cebola Média</li>
                            <li>Azeite</li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="card-text">Deixe a couve-flor picada. Adicione os ingredientes e refogue bem. Adicione sal, tampe a panela e deixe cozinhar.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 300px; height: 510px">
                        <img src="img/receita-2-230x170.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="receita-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Bolo de Café</h5>
                            <ul>
                            <li>Farinha de Trigo</li>
                            <li>Açúcar</li>
                            <li>Café Coado</li>
                            <li>Chocolate em Pó</li>
                            <li>Ovos</li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="card-text">Bata o açúcar, as gemas e o café. Adicione farinha e chocolate e mexa bem. Bata as claras e junte à mistura.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 300px; height: 510px">
                        <img src="img/receita-3-230x170.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="receita-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Coxinha de Brigadeiro</h5>
                            <ul>
                            <li>Leite Condensado</li>
                            <li>Chocolate em Pó</li>
                            <li>Manteiga</li>
                            <li>Morango</li>
                            <li>Chocolate Granulado</li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="card-text">Junte o leite condensado, chocolate em pó e manteiga. Aqueça no fogo baixo. Envolva os morangos e passe no granulado.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score -2):

Se vc quer utilizar o bootstrap pra gerir os tamanhos não deve utilizar um width fixo, pois assim você sobrepõe o código.

Tire as medidas e use o card-group do boostrap e se resolve.

Recomendo a leitura da documentação: [Documentação Boostrap Card Groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-groups)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://marketplace.canva.com/EAFD-jSDkY4/1/0/1131w/canva-receita-de-chocolate-quente-a4-vvTzPdct2CA.jpg"
                        class="card-img-top" alt="receita-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Arroz de Couve-Flor</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Arroz</li>
                            <li>Couve-Flor</li>
                            <li>Cebola Média</li>
                            <li>Azeite</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="card-text">Deixe a couve-flor picada. Adicione os ingredientes e refogue bem.
                            Adicione sal, tampe a panela e deixe cozinhar.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://marketplace.canva.com/EAFD-jSDkY4/1/0/1131w/canva-receita-de-chocolate-quente-a4-vvTzPdct2CA.jpg"
                        class="card-img-top" alt="receita-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Bolo de Café</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Farinha de Trigo</li>
                            <li>Açúcar</li>
                            <li>Café Coado</li>
                            <li>Chocolate em Pó</li>
                            <li>Ovos</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="card-text">Bata o açúcar, as gemas e o café. Adicione farinha e chocolate e mexa
                            bem. Bata as claras e junte à mistura.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://marketplace.canva.com/EAFD-jSDkY4/1/0/1131w/canva-receita-de-chocolate-quente-a4-vvTzPdct2CA.jpg"
                        class="card-img-top" alt="receita-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Coxinha de Brigadeiro</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Leite Condensado</li>
                            <li>Chocolate em Pó</li>
                            <li>Manteiga</li>
                            <li>Morango</li>
                            <li>Chocolate Granulado</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="card-text">Junte o leite condensado, chocolate em pó e manteiga. Aqueça no fogo
                            baixo. Envolva os morangos e passe no granulado.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas mesmo agora com o grupo de cards ele ainda não entra no responsivo https://prnt.sc/qby8bBqz_83z

Comment: Atualiza seu código na pergunta deixando ele com alguma imagem de exemplo. Se Analise também se vc não tem outro CSS influenciando. Lembre-se de tirar o width do seu estilo ou use um width: auto. Outra dica crie um codepen e coloque seu exemplo. Fica mais fácil a gente debugar

Comment: Eu estou dando meus pulos aqui, obrigado kkkk comecei agora com o bootstrap e não acho que ele seja difícil, mas acho que eu tenho que saber todas as classes dele pra conseguir utilizar ele, ate onde eu entendi pra ele deixar meu site 100% responsivo eu não posso adicionar nenhum width, certo?

Comment: Normal no começo kkkk, mas tudo é costume. Sim, pense no seguinte, o bootstrap já tem o formato de grid e tem vários break-points, ou seja se ajusta em cada tamanho. Se vc forçar um width no conteúdo que deveria ser dinamico, vc sobrepõe a regra. Leia a documentação e veja exemplos que funciona. O que coloquei no meu exemplo só troquei as imagens pq não tinha as suas e funcionou pois tirei os width e o col-md-3. O próprio cards do bootstrap se ajusta.

Comment: Entendi, no caso não tem nenhuma página que explique oque esses código das classes são? tipo esse "col-md-3" eu so usei ele pois vi em um vídeo mas nem sei oq significa kkkkk e sobre a grid do bootstrap eu tentei colocar 1 footer sem width nem height e ele fica abaixo do header kkkkk ai no caso eu teria q fazer como pra descer ele la pro final da página?

Comment: Tem explicação sim, por isso recomendo vc ler tudo lá. col como sugere é coluna md é pra telas do tipo medio, e o 3 significa usar 3 colunas do grid (total de 12). Leia aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ Não lembro as tags agora pro footer mas olha lá no link da resposta que mostra como usar o footer